# Cannot read data from telnet connection

Tags: java, sockets, telnet

I'm trying to make a simple telnet client, using Sockets in java. Here is what I've written:

```
public class NetUtil {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Socket sock = new Socket("localhost", 23);
        InputStream in = sock.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

        String output;
        while((output=br.readLine())!=null){
            System.out.println(output);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that output freezes when trying to read from buffered reader. I've checked connection with sock.isConnected() - its connected. My telnet server is up and running - i've checked from console - i can connect to my workstation, but when i try using sockets, it fails.

Comment: I think you should do the telnet handshake before attempting to read from the socket. Telnet is not as trivial protocol as it may initially seem. Edit: never mind the previous comment

Comment: I dont think i get it - you mean try writing username/password to socket before reading from it?

Comment: You need to provide the server information about the client terminal (encoding, echo status, etc) Study the RFCs, if you wish to do your own implementation (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telnet)

Comment: Okay, thanks for advice. At least i know where to get started.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you should reinvent the wheel here. Try using Apache Commons Net telnet client.

Comment: Well, i guess that would be the easiest way, but i;m curious about what goes wrong :) - i just cant see any reasons for such problem to appear

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure, that the server sends something? Does it send newline character as well? Your program is expecting it with calling `readLine` of `BufferedReader`.

Comment: Yes, i was trying same thing, using Runtime - and i had all the output, i expected...

Recently i checked my input stream 'in' - it contains some data, but converting it to char fails.

Comment: Do you see an exception? What does it mean 'fails'?

Comment: No exceptions - i just tried to print output like this:   
some_int=in.read();
System.out.print((char) some_int);